# SQL query time difference when adding an inner join and group by gives wrong calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to come up with an sql query to calculate, the time difference from a start time and an end time, then sum up the duration for each school.

I have the following table :

1. -Class /*Contains all the classes tied to a school using school_id */
2. -School /*contains all the schools in tied to a hub using hub_id */
3. -Hub /*contains all the hubs details (one hub can have many schools in it)  */
4. -student /*contains student profile, which is tied to a class using class_id */
5. -session_details /*contains the session details which include the session start time, end time, session_id,*/
6. -student_attendance_register /* used to mark the register for all the students in a class for a particular session using session_id
   and student_id as in_attendance=0 or in_attendance =1 /*

I have a mini query which works perfect, the query calculates the duration of the session and finds the total duration for all the classes in a school.

```
select
 c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start,
 CAST(sum(TIMEDIFF(e.time_finish, e.time_start)) as TIME) as duration 
 From session_details as e
                Inner join class as c
                    on c.id = e.class_id
                Inner join school as d 
                    on c.school_id = d.id       
                    group by c.school_id;
```

My problem pops up when i add inner joins to get the student profile and their attendance. See below my query

```
select 
    a.session_details_id,c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,
    e.class_id,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start,
    SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_start))/60) as session_duration,
                     COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_present,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
                    from session_details as e
                        inner join class as c
                            on c.id = e.class_id
                        inner join school as d 
                            on c.school_id = d.id
                    inner join attendance_student as a
                            on e.id = a.session_details_id
                    inner join student as b
                            on a.student_id = b.id
                    group by c.school_id;
```

Image 1 shows the results set without with group for all session that were done for each class in a school. This returns correct time duration.

[image: Image 1 shows the results set without with group for all session that were done for each class in a school. This returns correct time duration.]

Image 2 shows the result set with group for all session that we done for each class in a school.
[image: Image 2 shows the result set with group for all session that we done for each class in a school.]

When running query 2, whereby which is an extension of query one for adding the student profile and the total no of students who were in attendance.

[image: When running query 2, whereby which is an extension of query one for adding the student profile and the total no of students who were in attendance.]

When running query 2,without grouping by shool_id i get the following results
[image: When running query 2,without grouping by shool_id i get the following results]

**Note**
-I have tried to change the time to seconds then do the division then convert to minutes which return the wrong total.

```
sum((TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_start)))/60 as duration
```

-I have also tried to do a sum for the time finish in second, subtract the finish and start time then divide the total

-Am also in doubt of how am doing my inner joins, and maybe the problem lies in there, since once i introduce the inner joins to students i get the errors. Other totals are working ok except for my finish and start time which are time data type on the database.

> Here is a link to the related tables.
>
> Kindly assit on how best to go about doing a correct calculation for the duration once i inner join and group the tables. :)
>
> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36bb8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood all the details, the problem is in the `group by`. You must group by every field with no aggregation function (like `SUM` or `COUNT`). Using your second SQL query you change the `group by` like this :

```
select 
    a.session_details_id,c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,
    e.class_id,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start,
    SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_start))/60) as session_duration,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
from session_details as e
    inner join class as c
      on c.id = e.class_id
    inner join school as d 
      on c.school_id = d.id
    inner join attendance_student as a
      on e.id = a.session_details_id
    inner join student as b
      on a.student_id = b.id
group by a.session_details_id,c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,
    e.class_id,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start
```

But, then, the `SUM` in the `session_duration` calculation, add the total duration for each student, so you need to make calculation of `session_duration` without aggregation function:

```
select 
    a.session_details_id,c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,
    e.class_id,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(e.time_start))/60 as     session_duration,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as     boys_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  b.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
from session_details as e
    inner join class as c
      on c.id = e.class_id
    inner join school as d 
      on c.school_id = d.id
    inner join attendance_student as a
      on e.id = a.session_details_id
    inner join student as b
      on a.student_id = b.id
group by a.session_details_id,c.class_name,c.school_id,d.school_name,
    e.class_id,e.session_date,e.time_finish,e.time_start
```

If you run this query on SQLFiddle you provide, your results are:

[image: Results in SQLFiddle]

**-- Edited --**

After your comments I'll try again ;)

If you strip off `class_id`, `session_date`, `time_start`, `time_finish` to only get totals by school, this query will do the work:

```
select 
  c.school_id, sc.school_name,
  sum((TIME_TO_SEC(sd.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(sd.time_start))/60) as session_duration,
  sum(stc.boys_present) boys_present, sum(stc.girls_present) girls_present,
  sum(stc.boys_absent) boys_absent, sum(stc.girls_absent) girls_absent,
  sum(stc.boys_total) boys_total, sum(stc.girls_total) girls_total
  from session_details sd
       inner join (
          select a.session_details_id,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_present,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
            from attendance_student a
                 inner join student s
                       on a.student_id = s.id
           group by a.session_details_id
         ) stc
        on sd.id = stc.session_details_id
      inner join class c
        on sd.class_id = c.id
      inner join school sc
        on c.school_id = sc.id
 group by c.school_id, sc.school_name
```

Here I use a different approach making a subquery (maybe you prefer save as a view) to calculate student assistance totals.

First I count the students for each session using only two tables, `attendance_student` and `student`. Results are grouped by th ID os the session, so I have students by session. This query can be saved as a view for readability.

```
select a.session_details_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
  from attendance_student a
       inner join student s
             on a.student_id = s.id
 group by a.session_details_id
```

) stc

After that I join this results with `session_details` to calculate `session_duration` for each session. Our resultset now has a `session_details_id`, `session_duration` and the count of students (one row for each session).

```
select 
  sd.id as session_id,
  (TIME_TO_SEC(sd.time_finish) - TIME_TO_SEC(sd.time_start))/60 as session_duration,
  sum(stc.boys_present) boys_present, sum(stc.girls_present) girls_present,
  sum(stc.boys_absent) boys_absent, sum(stc.girls_absent) girls_absent,
  sum(stc.boys_total) boys_total, sum(stc.girls_total) girls_total
  from session_details sd
       inner join (
          select a.session_details_id,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_present,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 1 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_present,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_absent,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN a.in_attendance = 0 and s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_absent,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 2 then 1 END) as girls_total,
              COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 1 then 1 END) as boys_total
            from attendance_student a
                 inner join student s
                       on a.student_id = s.id
           group by a.session_details_id
         ) stc
        on sd.id = stc.session_details_id
```

We want to sum results by school so we need add to more tables, `class` and `school`. We don't really need `class` table to show any data but an intermediate table to get school data.

Comment: from your result set i need to add the total duration for schools which are similar. In this case i need to group school_id = 11 to get a duration of 150. Thank you

Comment: If you group by school ID you loose detail information about class and session. ¿What I must do with students counts and time_start or time_finish? ¿Can you provide a exact resultset with this sample dataset?

Comment: This is the results set i expect http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36bb8/45 but once i add the inner joins to get the total for boys and girls the result set changes.

Comment: You're adding session_duration for two different classes (4M and 5M), take one of two names (4M) and his start and finish hour? If you group by class then you have three rows in your resultset (one for each class), if you group by school, you can't get class fields which are not under an aggregation function, maybe you can use a function like `min(time_start)` or `max(time_finish)` or `min(class_name)` but, class '4M' have a session duration of 120 and '5M' of 30. In your resulset you say: class '4M' has a session duration of 150, true for school_id=11, not for class '4M'.

Comment: Tony take a school scenario, we have different  of classes for a particular school. Having that in mind, I need to calculate the total duration for all the classes in a school there by the need for grouping by school_id. I cannot use max as these sessions  start & end at different times and are captured at different durations.You can relate this in a school setting as PE sessions for different classes for different days,whereby we are capturing the student who attended. All these details are captured in the session_details table. I hope you can now relate to my dataset

Comment: this one works perfect :) . But I don't understand what you've done . Kindly do inline comments or  on your on  why my query was not working and when to apply your approach thank you. So that someone can use or adapt the answer.

Comment: I'll try to explain how I proceed to _construct_ the SQL query, but I'm not sure if it's clear enough